# Is it dangerous to display user-input in url

Tags: node.js, security, url, express, user-input

I am using node.js and express4

In my app, users can write posts and give them a title. I will generate an unique ID for each post.

One can then access to a post via the url :  *domain/posts/ID-of-the-post/title-of-the-post*
Server-side, after parsing the url, I only use the ID of the post to correctly query my database.
I never use the title of the post from the url because I get it safely from my database.

So basically, the url *domain/posts/A-valid-ID-of-a-post/**ANYTHING*** points to the page of a post.

**My question is: is this dangerous? can some attacker take advantage of this?**
If yes, how can I protect myself?

Note: 
I am protected against html injection so my question is only about the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is safe but you should consider [percent encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the string.

Certain characters have special meanings to the browser, such as the `#` character, which is used to lookup an anchor tag for scrolling (in the format `<a name="foo">` ) and is also available to JavaScript as the `window.location.hash` property. Depending on your site and its JavaScript code and if data is read from this property, it could be possible for an attacker to launch a [DOM based XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_Based_XSS) attack. While allowing the `#` character in your URL will not affect whether such a vulnerability exists or not, if there is such a vulnerability an attacker might be able to leverage this functionality with another attack by purposely creating a URL containing this character which will enable any dynamically generated links on your site to execute the attack. Without this leverage, the victim would have to follow a link from the attacker instead (e.g. from an email or a forum). **Bottom line: It is better to percent encode or remove the `#` character to be safe.**

[You should also percent encode (or remove) other special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1547940/413180), specifically anything outside of the following:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-._~:/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;=
```

as these characters are the only ones valid in a URL according to [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt).

Comment: I have tried using the # as an entry point to follow a link: I added a link on the page with the id "bar" and I entered "foo#bar" as post title. Hopefully all it did was scrolling the link but not following it. Anyway I will now precent encode, just to be on the safe side

Answer (score 1):

You can use it, in fact I have seen many sites/forums and the stackoverflow itself using this method, for instance look at the current url of a webpage:

`stackoverflow.com/questions/25763180/is-it-dangerous-to-display-user-input-in-url`

It is not that dangerous, just keep in mind that it is *Unsanitized input* and treat it accordingly - a potential input attack (actually, do that always!)

Answer (score 0):

It is safe, if you implement some basic security precautions in place.

If your post ID is a numeric value, you could just check if the value is a valid positive number. If yes, continue, otherwise, return an error or show a `404` page.

If your post ID is a string value, there is a chance of SQL injection if your storage is an RDBMS. In such case, the underlying DBMS module should provide a function to escape string values. For instance, [node-cubrid](https://github.com/CUBRID/node-cubrid), a Node module for CUBRID Database, has [_escapeString()](https://github.com/CUBRID/node-cubrid/blob/master/src/utils/Helpers.js#L167) helper function.

Once you implement these basic checks and sanitisation, it's safe to put the post ID in the URL.

Answer (score -1):

Whether it's dangerous in terms of security I don't know, but you shouldn't do this even if it's safe.  Many characters can cause confusion for users (e.g. anything non-visible, homograms), or for robots (`#`, `?`).   URLs have specific syntax, and letting users jam any old string in them is not a good design.  Sanitize them to only contain e.g. lowercase letters and dashes and numbers, the way many sites (including Stack Overflow) do.

Comment: stackexchange will disagree with you, check out the URL to this page. Pretty URL is a way forward to improve UX

Comment: Stack Exchange does sanitize before building URLs: e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25763974/oclint-error-no-rule-loaded has colons in the title but not the URL!

Comment: Yes it does. But a need to sanitize user input is not a reason to drop the whole UX enhancement idea.

Comment: I think this answer didnt deserve a votedown. (don't have enough reputation point to vote up though)