# oclint: error: no rule loaded

Tags: macos, static-code-analysis, oclint

I am trying to get the list of warnings,errors,syntax coding convention and cyclomatic complexity from command line. I found that oclint can be used for my purpose. but then I ran into a problem

What I tried to do.

```
xcodebuild -project testing.xcodeproj -target "testing" -configuration "Debug" -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPad" -sdk "iphonesimulator7.0" -IDEBuildOperationMaxNumberOfConcurrentCompileTasks=8 clean
xcodebuild -project testing.xcodeproj -target "testing" -configuration "Debug" -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPad" -sdk "iphonesimulator7.0" -IDEBuildOperationMaxNumberOfConcurrentCompileTasks=8 build |tee xcodebuild.log
```

> oclint-xcodebuild xcodebuild.log

till here everything went fine and even compile_commands.json was created correctly.

but when I ran `oclint-json-compilation-database` then I am getting this error.

I read from [here](http://docs.oclint.org/en/dev/manual/oclint.html) that i must use `oclint [-enable-clang-static-analyzer]` after the above command succeeds

If anyone knows how to solve this or have a better solution for my requirement Please let me know

EDIT:
if I use `clint [-enable-clang-static-analyzer -R /usr/lib/oclint/rules ]` then I am getting the error `oclint: error: cannot find dynamic library for report type: text`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my problem. posting the solution as it can help some one.

My problem is, i cloned the repository and pasted the script files in usr/local/lib manually and that somehow is not right!. what I did is removed those and did a brew install.

here is the command

```
brew install https://raw.github.com/ryuichisaito6/homebrew/f12a21dd274899ef9ab14cd97e45f315dd982cf6/Library/Formula/oclint.rb
```

Thanks

Comment: try 0.9 as it is less buggy